# nodejs and mongoose. Return a limited number of each element that satisfies a query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In mongoose querying.  If I was to query documents that match an array of conditions, i.e number in [1, 3, 7, 9]. How would I limit the number of each match to be returned, rather than limit the total overall documents returned.

I could do it by iterating over the array and querying the documents by individual number and limiting the quantity of returned documents, then push them to an array of returned documents, but this would be time consuming and costly, increasing the query response time by n * array element to query.

Is there an easier way to do this?  can anyone suggest an alternative?

Best regards,

Jonathan.